# Can I do something like below for frozen class method in ruby

Tags: ruby

- Here I need to update the admin password in the frozen format.
- I tried something like the below which is not updating the data and giving errors like "  can't modify frozen Class: SecureCredentials"

```
module Frontend
  def given_credentials
    users.each do |user|
      if user.username == 'admin'
        user.username='admin'
        user.password='chnage_password'
        return SecureCredentials.new(user.username, user.password)
      end
    end
  end

  class SecureLogin
    ADMIN = SecureCredentials.new('admin', 'old_password')
    # Gets all users from the database
    def self.users
      from_json = ->(data) { SecureCredentials.new(data['user'], data['pw']).freeze }
      credentials = JSON.load(USER_DATA).map(&from_json).to_set
      credentials << ADMIN
      credentials.freeze
    end

    def logged_in?
      !user.nil?
    end

    def admin?
      user == ADMIN
    end

    def login!
      @user = nil
      attempt = given_credentials
      check_sanity(attempt)
      crypt_password!(attempt)
      check_credentials!(attempt)
      puts welcome
    end

    private

    # Make sure we’re not dealing with malicious objects
    def check_sanity(given)
      fail unless String(given.username) == given.username
      fail unless String(given.password) == given.password
    end

    # Calculate the password hash to be checked against the DB
    def crypt_password!(given)
      given.password = given.password.crypt(SALT)
    end

    # Check username and password against the DB
    def check_credentials!(given)
      all_users = self.class.users

      if all_users.include?(given)
        user = all_users.find { |u| u.username == given.username }
        @user = user if (user.password == given.password)
      end
    end

    def user
      @user ||= nil
    end

    def welcome
      if logged_in?
        msg = "Welcome, #{user.username}."
        msg << (admin? ? " You have administrator rights." : "")
      else
        "Login denied"
      end
    end

  end

  SALT = 'you_cannot_break_this'

  USER_DATA = <<-EOF
    [
      { "user": "user1", "pw": "qweqweq" },
      { "user": "user2",  "pw": "HD5w8ws" },
      { "user": "user3", "pw": "yr/D1uY" },
      { "user": "user4", "pw": "y1CIy0O." },
      { "user": "user5",   "pw": "bdHVHnQ" }
    ]
  EOF
end

class SecureCredentials
  def self.new
    if self.username == "admin"
      self.password = "chnage_password" 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would say that modifying a frozen object shouldn't be possible; but you can still replace it with an other one.

Comment: Can you guide me with code for replace

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example?

Comment: simply i need to change the admin password from the given_credentials method but I can not modify it as its frozen array